# How to enable touch event emulation in web browsers?

Tags: browser

How can I enable the touch event emulation in web browsers? Specifically, Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

For Chrome, I found [an article](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation), but I cannot find overrides tab in the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a feature of Chrome's development tools.

Press <kbd>cmd</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to open the inspector, then use the cog in the bottom right.

[image: Cog]

Switch to the overrides vertical tab...

[image: Overrides]

...and then check *Emulate touch events*.

[image: Emulate touch events]

Comment: Thank you! what about other browsers?

Comment: @user1709201 I'm not sure if the other browsers provide a setting out-of-the-box. Possibly there are plugins, or you could add a bit of JavaScript which detects the mouse equivalents and dispatches the touch events.